# Retrieve key's value from registered variable in ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am writing various playbooks for the provisioning of users, groups, policies etc in AWS.

At the moment, I am trying to write a task that will remove any access keys from a given AWS IAM account. To properly do so using the iam module in ansible, you must specify the AWS access key that you wish to disable.

This script also creates a user before hand (the removing of access keys is to assure that if the user was already created, they don't have any left over access keys from before).

The output of the user creation is registered into a variable like so

```
- name: Create new user and add to IAM group for console
  vars:
    use_key: "{{ enable_access_keys }}"
  iam:
    iam_type: user
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
    aws_access_key: "{{ account_vars.aws_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ account_vars.aws_secret_key }}"
    password: "{{ iam_password }}"
    update_password: on_create
  with_items:
    - "{{ iam_user_name_list }}"
  when: not use_key
  register: console_user
```

The output of the console_user var is:

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "changed": false,
                "groups": null,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "access_key_ids": null,
                        "access_key_state": null,
                        "aws_access_key": "removed",
                        "aws_secret_key": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                        "ec2_url": null,
                        "groups": null,
                        "iam_type": "user",
                        "key_count": 1,
                        "name": "other-guy",
                        "new_name": null,
                        "new_path": null,
                        "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                        "path": "/",
                        "profile": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "security_token": null,
                        "state": "present",
                        "trust_policy": null,
                        "trust_policy_filepath": null,
                        "update_password": "on_create",
                        "validate_certs": true
                    }
                },
                "item": "other-guy",
                "keys": {
                    "Access key is here": "Active"
                },
                "user_name": "other-guy"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I get the access key that is provided under the "keys" dictionary? Since the what I'm looking for is the key, not the value, I'm not sure how I would go about obtaining that access key so I can use it in the next task to say that I'd like to remove it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `.keys()` method for every dictionary. For example to print keys for each user:

```
- debug:
    msg: "User {{ item.user_name }} has keys {{ item.keys.keys() }}"
  with_items: "{{ console_user.results }}"
```

Or to iterate over every key of every user with JMESPath:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ console_user.results | json_query('[].keys.keys(@)') }}"
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. For some reason ansible doesn't like the .keys directly on the variable because it seems to think we want to call keys() (console_user.results[0].keys just returns "builtin_function_or_method object" instead of the KV pairs in the dictionary). I had to end up using the json query but that did the trick.