# Ansible: How to output home folder names with invalid user ID's?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to output home folder names with invalid user id's to a register within ansible.

I can get the first part. It's simple enough:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:

  - name: Build array of home folders
    shell: "ls -lh /home | awk '{print $9}' | grep c"
    register: home_folders
```

The next part is tricky for me as a new Ansible user

```yaml
  - name: Determine invalid user folders
    shell: "getent passwd {{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ home_folders.stdout_lines }}"
    register: invalid_user_folders
    failed_when: invalid_user_folders.rc != 2
    ignore_errors: true
```

How to register a failed Shell command in Ansible correctly?

For reference, here is a simple Bash script that does it by seeing whether the `getent` output is nothing, then it knows the user doesn't exist.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
array=($(ls -lh /home | awk '{ print $9 }'))

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
        firstletter=${i:0:1}
        if [ $firstletter == c ]
        then

                temp=$(getent passwd $i)

                removable=$(echo "$temp" )
                if [ -z "$removable" ]
                then
                        echo "$i"
                fi

        fi

done
```

Am I going about this the right way in Ansible? Is there another/better way to do it?

Comment: According your description I assume your use case is to delete home folders which do not have a local user account. To list the directories under `/home` it is recommend to use the [`find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html)_module. To get all user it is recommended to use [`getent`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html)_module and to remove the home folders later [`user`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html)_module with parameter `remove`.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I'm looking for. I'll look into those modules and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

According your description I assume your use case is to delete home folders which do not have a local user account.

The command `ls -lh /home | awk '{print $9}'` will deliver incorrect results in example in mixed domain with MS AD DC and Linux hosts and domain groups with space in name (i.e. `domain member`).

So to list the directories under `/home` it is recommend to use the [`find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html)_module whereby you register the result.

```yaml
- name: List all user directories
  find:
    paths: /home
    file_type: directory
  register: result
```

To access the full path and to get the home directory name you could use

```yaml
- name: Show result
  debug:
    msg: "Full path: {{ item.path}}, basename: {{ item.path | basename }}"
  loop: "{{ result.files }}"
```

The `result.files` contains the full path and to get the last name of a file path you could use the [`basename`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) filter by [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)ing over the result.

To get all local user information you could use [`getent`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html)_module.

```yaml
- name: Get all local user info
  getent:
    database: passwd

- name: Show all user info
  debug:
    var: getent_passwd
```

To loop over the their contained local users isn't that easy. Just by trying to loop over the datastructure you would get an error

```
Invalid data passed to ''loop'', it requires a list, got this instead ...
```

So to show the user name only

```yaml
- name: Show local user names
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ getent_passwd.keys() | list }}"
```

you need to make a [`| list`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) of all the [`.keys()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44789250/6771046) before.

To make sure that users are absent including their directories you may use the [`user`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html#examples)_module with parameters `state: absent` and `remove: yes`.